# Configure Outlier detection for consul service mesh using nomad job

Tags: consul, circuit-breaker, nomad, servicemesh

I am trying to configure Outlier Detection for a consul connect service mesh based on this documentation.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/service-mesh-circuit-breaking?in=consul/developer-mesh

The documentation shows that Outlier Detection and Circuit breaking can be configured using the config stanza inside proxy.upstreams. But the following job file throws error - `Blocks of type "config" are not expected here.`

```
job "docs" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]

  group "docs" {
    network {
      mode = "bridge"
    }
    service {
      name = "docs"
      port = "5678"

      connect {
        sidecar_service {
          proxy {
            upstreams {
              destination_name = "demo"
              local_bind_port  = 10082
              config {
                connect_timeout_ms = 3000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    task "server" {
      driver = "docker"

      config {
        image = "hashicorp/http-echo"
        args = [
          "-listen",
          ":5678",
          "-text",
          "hello world",
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is this not the right way to configure circuit breaking in nomad job file?

Answer (score 0):

**sidecar Proxy, Circuit breaking, ingress, egress** must be implemented with consul directly and not **from nomad**. Also, In your job you didn't map the port inside docker and outside port. consul work a specific version of envoy **load balacner**.

> 1. First launch your job without connect stanza and do port mapping
> 2. install envoy and do proxy connect connection manually to test
> 3. once test work make a service proxy to launch your sidecar your circuit breaking
>
> ### 1- Launching job: (by exemple your port inside docker is 8080 )

```
job "docs" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]

  group "docs" {
    network {
      mode = "bridge"
    }
    
    task "server" {
      driver = "docker"

      config {
        image = "hashicorp/http-echo"
        args = [
          "-listen",
          ":5678",
          "-text",
          "hello world",
        ]
        port_map {
            docs = 8080
        }
      }
      resources {
           network {
               mbits = 10
               port "docs" { static = 5678 }
           }
      }
  service {
    name = "docs"
    port = "docs"
    check {
      name     = "docs port alive"
      type     = "http"
      path     = "/"
      interval = "10s"
      timeout  = "2s"
    }
  }
    }
  }
}
```

> ### 2-check your consul version and install supported envoy version [here](https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/proxies/envoy). i use consul 1.11 so i  will install supported envoy 1.18.4

```
yum -y -q install tar
curl https://func-e.io/install.sh | bash -s -- -b /usr/local/bin
func-e use 1.18.4
```

make the envoy bin available

```
cp /root/.func-e/versions/1.18.4/bin/envoy /usr/local/bin/
```

#### `Proxy integration`

insert at your end of consul config .for me my config are stored in

**`/etc/consul.d/config.hcl`**

```
config_entries {
  bootstrap = [
    {
      kind = "proxy-defaults"
      name = "global"
      config {
        protocol                   = "http"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### `**restart your consul service to check if envoy proxy integration worked**`

```
systemctl restart consul
```

#### `Overwrite your service registration in consul with consul file :`

cat > /etc/consul.d/docs.hcl <<- EOF

```
service {
  name = "docs"
  port = 5678
  #token = "" # put api service token here
  check {
    id = "docs"
    name = "HTTP API on Port 5678"
    http = "http://localhost:5678"
    interval = "30s"
  }
  connect {
    sidecar_service {
      port = 20000
      check {
        name     = "Connect Envoy Sidecar"
        tcp      = "127.0.0.1:20000"
        interval = "10s"
      }
    }
  }
}
EOF
```

### `restart service consul or reload it`

```
systemctl restart consul
```

#### `Test proxy side car working`

consul connect envoy -sidecar-for=docs

#### `create docs service proxy` Create at **/etc/systemd/system/consul-envoy-docs.service** and input the following:

```
cat > /etc/systemd/system/consul-envoy.service <<- EOF
[Unit]
Description=Consul Envoy
After=syslog.target network.target 
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/consul connect envoy -sidecar-for=docs
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 5
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

#### `Restart consul and start consul-envoy:`

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart consul
systemctl start consul-envoy-docs
```

#### `In the event that consul-envoy fails, restart it with:`

```
systemctl restart consul-envoy
```

> ## 3. Well if all work correctly , adapt conf file in **/etc/systemd/system/consul-envoy-docs.service** as described [here](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/service-mesh-circuit-breaking?in=consul/developer-mesh) to make circuit breaking

```
If someone have issue with nomad , consul , vault , envoy or hashistack tag me
```